# How to call JS function from script tag added on index.html in AngularJS factory

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, function, typescript

We have AngularJS application.
I have placed one script reference on index.html

```
<script src="cdn-path-of-refered-file.js"></script>
```

Now my concern is, I want to call one function in my factory, but I not able to call that. May be due to it does not understand where to look for.

```
case "newCase": 
{
    functiontocall();
}
```

But it is not getting that function, what will be the best approach in this case.

Comment: How about using $window ? `$window.functionToCall();`
Another reason could be that your script tag is loaded too late (after your AngularJS Factory script)

Comment: @ThomasMauduit-Blin No, It loaded before. As I called this function one button click, its available to us.

Comment: @ConstantLearner so you called the function with a button click, how did you bind it? `onclick=` what? However you referred the function is the same way you call it in your file. However, take precautionary measures.... there is a SUPER HIGH chance that it is not loaded when you are trying to call it.